# Eclipse plugin to copy names of committed classes

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I need help finding the name for the pluggin or setting in eclipse that allows me to copy the names of all the files I commit in SVN. 
Here is an screenshot of the general area I would like the button to be.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4wmU.png

Answer (score 2):

Open Console view and then from the drop down on the top right corner select Subversion console. There you should see log of all operations, including committed files.